# upload file on firebase web using node js throws error firebase.storage is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

i created a web app using node js express and firebase. i created a form which will upload a file to firebase but when i tried what's on the guide it gives an error..

```
var firebase = require('firebase');

var config = {
  apiKey: "----------------------------------",
  authDomain: "----------------------------------",
  databaseURL: "-",----------------------------------
  projectId: "---------",
  storageBucket: "----------------",
  messagingSenderId: "---------------"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

module.exports = firebase;

// Get a reference to the storage service, which is used to create references in your storage bucket
var storage = firebase.storage();

// Create a storage reference from our storage service
var storageRef = storage.ref();
```

this is the set up i use for using firebase on node js.

```
var storage = firebase.storage();
                       ^
TypeError: firebase.storage is not a function
```

and this is the error i receive from the console. after searching they said that i need to use google-cloud npm. so my question is if i install google-cloud on my node do i need to create an account on google cloud platform?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node js google-cloud package is used instead of firebase to store files, videos etc. Right now firebase storage is not compatible with Nodejs that's why you are getting that error^, yoou can do something like this to use google-cloud:-

```
npm install --save google-cloud
```

And then to use storage in your project this is a sample code:-

```
const gcloud = require('google-cloud');

const storage = gcloud.storage({
projectId: //project id here,
keyFilename: //service account credentials here,
});

const storagebucket = storage.bucket('projectID.appspot.com');
```

This link here has the complete guide how to do google-cloud stuff.

```
 https://medium.com/@stardusteric/nodejs-with-firebase-storage-c6ddcf131ceb
```

Comment: why can i get my service account credential?.

Comment: here you can make one or use existing.....https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication

Comment: i got an error ...`var storage-bucket = storage.bucket('iwatcher-a1e76.appspot.com');
           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token -`

Comment: give any name to the variable lol "-" cant be used as variable names.

Comment: i replace it.. thanks but following what is on link you provided after trying i always lands on this script..  `blobStream.on('error', (error) => {
      reject('Something is wrong! Unable to upload at the moment.');
    }); `